# Given an LP problem how to transform the problem?

Tags: linear-programming

Given the following problem:

$$ \max. -3x_1 -2x_2 - \frac{9}{2}$$
$$ \text{s.t.} -x_1 + x_2 \le 0$$
$$      5x_1 + 3x_2 \le 8$$
$$ x_1,x_2 \ge 0 $$

When we convert the LP into standard form and then write down the simplex tableau we see that the starting solution is already optimal:$$  x_3 ,x_4  \rightarrow \text{basic variables} $$
$$ x_1, x_2 \rightarrow \text{nonbasic variables}$$ Is it possible to transform the original problem so that the starting solution will be another extreme point?

Comment: There is only one optimal solution $(x_1^*,x_2^*)=(0,0)$. It cannot be changed by transforming the original problem. It can only be changed if we change the problem.

Comment: @callculus I am not trying to change the optimal solution. I want to change the problem such that we will start from another basis. Not the basis with the variables (x3,x4)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(1,1,0,0)$ is also a basic feasible solution.

That is we pick the basis using the first tow columns rather than the last two columns, that is $B=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 5 & 3\end{bmatrix}$.

Rather than $Ax=b$, we have

$$(B^{-1}A )x = (B^{-1}b)$$

Comment: But the table is optimal when we pick basic variables as x3 and x4 already. Choosing x1 and x2 as basic variables would make us go back to a nonoptimal basic feasible solution than we will come back to a solution where x3 and x4 give optimal value again

Comment: The problem should be modified , the equations should change but the corner points when plugged in objective function should give the same values as  the original problem.